# Reducing a third order ODE to a first order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the IVP:

$x^{'''}(t) - ax^{''}(t) - bx'(t) - cx = f(t)$

With initial conditions:

$x(0) = \phi , x'(0) = \eta , x^{''}(0) = \theta$

I am being asked to write this IVP as a first order system $x'(t) = Ax(t) + g(t)$, and here is what I have done so far:

Let $u = x$ , $v = u'$ , $w = v'$ then:

$u = x$

$u' = v$

$u'' = v' = w$

$u''' = v'' = w' = av' + bv + cu + f(t) = aw + bv + cu + f(t)$

However, how do I use this to write $x'(t) = Ax + g(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\pmatrix{u\\v\\w}'= \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\c&b&a} \pmatrix{u\\v\\w} + 
\pmatrix{0\\0\\f},\,  \pmatrix{u(0)\\v(0)\\w(0)} =\pmatrix{\phi\\\eta\\\theta}$$